# How to retrieve object members in @Query Annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a basic entity and I want to create a query that would retrieve this entity's members. Here is the entity:

```
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    @Column(insertable=false)
    private String db_id;
}
```

And my test repository in which I try to create the query.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
    @Query("INSERT INTO TestEntity VALUES (:object.id, :object.name :object.author)")
    void insertSynchronizedColumns(TestEntity object);
}
```

This currently throws error:

```
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting OPEN, found 'VALUES'
```

As a function argument I need the `object` and not the specific column names. Is there a way to retrieve `object`'s `id` and other fields?

Comment: How about `repo.save(object)`?

Comment: @JBNizet `save()` doesn't insert autogenerated `id` and I need to insert `id` aswell

Comment: @Rasmond `repo.saveAndFlush(object)`  ? Save should work though

Comment: Is it a nativeQuery?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a _comma_ between `:object.name` and `:object.author` in the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through `nativeQuery` as follows:

```
 @Modifying
 @Transactional
 @Query("INSERT INTO TestEntity VALUES (:#{#object.id}, :#{#object.name}, :#{#object.author})",nativeQuery=true)
 int insertSynchronizedColumns(@Param("object")TestEntity object);
```